# Twilio Outbound calls with Caller Id

Tags: twilio, verification, caller-id

We have a query to ask regarding the Twilio voice communication and hope you will help us.

We are having a client and they are having business with Health care domain having Doctor-Patient communication happening through Twilio cloud.

We know that a non-twilio number can be used for caller id after verification with twilio by 6 digit input from the user.

The client requires a mechanism like when they sell the product to many customers, each customer just input any valid work number (office number) and wants to use those number as Caller Id without the verification process.

We would like to know whether Twilio us offering such custom caller ids without doing the verification steps ? Like with means of a high-level membership plan with twilio or for utlizing any bulk purchase schemes or by trusting the client with any documents or by any other means of ?

Please give your suggestions in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to verify each number to use it for your caller ID. Another way of doing it is that you buy the number via Twilio when the customer signs up and that's their outbound caller ID. Would be much easier to do.

david